# Creating a math video library app. Need advice for how to store data

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, video

I am not a complete beginner at iOS development but I would appreciate some advice as to how to set up the source data file information for a video app I am making. I have created about 150+ calculus videos that I use to help my students learn calculus. They are all available for free at www.calcsuccess.org 
As part of learning iOS development on my own I want to create an iOS app that allows students to access them quickly with a native iOS app. This will be a simple application that simply consists of one or two Tableviews and when the students click on a Table cell it takes them to an AVPlayerView which shows the video hosted on my server. I started the app and hardcoded three videos and tested to make sure the segues are working properly and so on. If you are interested in the complete source code you can find it here:

https://github.com/gmoalvarez/calcsuccess

Ok, now on to my question:

Since there are hundreds of videos, each with a title and a url, what is a good way to store and retrieve this information from the app?

For example, right now I have a basic struct for the video

```
struct Video {
    var title:String?
    var chapter:String?
    var section:String?
    var path:String?
    var url:NSURL?
    //  var quality:String
    var description:String? {
        return title
    }
}
```

The table cell is set up to take the title of the video and show it on the cell. Should I look into creating a CSV file with these fields and then learning how to parse it using Swift? Any other ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest a JSON file hosted on your web site, this way you can edit it without having to re-submit your application.

You can easily parse JSON with Swift, it translates to a dictionary, which you can iterate through and create new instances of your struct and put them into an array to use with your UITableView.

I'd suggest this tutorial for working with JSON in Swift: http://www.raywenderlich.com/82706/working-with-json-in-swift-tutorial

Alternatively, if you don't want to implement it this way, you can ship a JSON file with your Xcode application and load it. (Just like you would a remote URL).

And finally, if you don't want to go that route I'd suggest Parse.com, it's a back end service with an awesome iOS API. You can manage your data on their back end and even import XML or CSV files. There's a small learning curve.

A remote JSON file or Parse.com will both let you alter the data without having to re-submit your app.

Answer (score 2):

You can use lots of different formats. I'd probably use JSON, since it's widely supported on a variety of hardware, easy to read "by eye" and not too verbose. iOS has the NSJSONSerialization class that will let you convert data back and forth between JSON and iOS container classes like arrays.

There's also the ALAMOFire library which is a lightweight Swift networking library that includes built-in JSON support.

An array of dictionaries should work fine for your application.